# Create Collection using variable name

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a loop to add collections to vba collections.

The top level collection is `columns`
I am looping over 7 days and the aim is to have a collection `column` for each day containing 6 values. At the end of the loop, `columns` contains 7 collections containing 42 values (7*6), obviously on each loop, column is not resetting to a new collection rather it adds to the 1st created collection.

```
    Do While startColNum <= endColNum

        Dim column As New Collection '-- how do i create a new collection here without changing the previous??


        For i = Startrow To Endrow
            ActiveString = Cells(i, startColNum).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            column.Add GetValue(path, file, sheet, ActiveString)
        Next i

        columns.Add column '-- this is the same collection, at the end of the loop each collection has 42 values.

        startColNum = startColNum + 1
    Loop
```

Is there a way to create a collection with a variable name? E.g.

`Set columns(i) = new collection`

Comment: Do you want to create an `array` of `collections` or do you simply want to reset the `collection` towards the end of your code with something like `Set column = Nothing`?

Comment: first off: `column` and `columns` are propertys and should not used as names for variables. and what you are looking for: dim the collection outside of the loop and start the loop with `Set MyCollection = New Collection` ;)

Comment: Ralph it was a collection of collections. Fair point @DirkReichel , using set does indeed work thanks for that. But one thing I was looking to get answered, in some languages you can define a variable using a variable which would be handy, is there anything like this in VBA?